# How to get rid of 2 numbers' common divisors

Tags: c++

So I have a function that divides a pair of numbers until they no longer have any common divisors:

```
void simplify(int &x, int &y){
    for (int i = 2;;++i){
        if (x < i && y < i){
            return;
        }
        while (1){
            if (!(x % i) && !(y % i)){
                x /= i;
                y /= i;
            } else {
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

How can I make it more efficient? I know one problem in this solution is that it tests for divisibility with compound numbers, when it wouldn't have any of it's factors by the time it gets to them, so it's just wasted calculations. Can I do this without the program knowing a set of primes beforehand/compute them during the function's runtime?

Comment: Not a problem, but `while (1) { if (condition) {...} else { break; }}` is usually written `while (condition) {...}`.

Comment: [Euclid published an algorithm for finding the greatest common divisor in *Elements*, book VII, propositions 1 and 2, around 300 BCE.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_algorithm)

Comment: @EricPostpischil • Is there an algorithm that is older?  Something that new is suspect because it hasn't had enough time for peer review and scrutinization.

Comment: @Eljay: If I recall correctly, then, according to *Mathematical Thought*, by Morris Kline, it has some claim on being the oldest published algorithm. But I am not sure what criteria Kline uses for “algorithm,” as surely things like addition must be earlier. One should note there is a [binary version of GCD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_GCD_algorithm) more suitable for computers that represent numbers with bits (which were unavailable to Euclid) and in which general division may be slower than operations like subtraction.

Answer (score 4):

Use [the Euclidean algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_algorithm)<sup>1</sup>:

1. Let *a* be the larger of two given positive integers and *b* be the smaller.
2. Let *r* be the remainder of *a* divided by *b*.
3. If *r* is zero, we are done, and *b* is the greatest common divisor.
4. Otherwise, let *a* take the value of *b*, let *b* take the value of *r*, and go to step 2.

Once you have the greatest common divisor, you can divide the original two numbers by it, which will yield two numbers with the same ratio but without any common factors greater than one.

## Citation

<sup>1</sup> Euclid, *Elements*, book VII, propositions 1 and 2, circa 300 BCE.

## Notes

Euclid used subtraction, which has been changed here to remainder.

Once this algorithm is working, you might consider the slightly more intricate [Binary GCD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_GCD_algorithm), which replaces division (which is slow on some processors) with subtraction and bit operations.

Comment: geometry pwns! nice reference :)

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like a job for the C++17 library feature [gcd](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/gcd).

```
#include <numeric>
void simplify(int &x, int &y)
{
    const auto d = std::gcd(x, y);
    x /= d;
    y /= d;
}
```

[Compiler Explorer](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/gCfAXa)